# How to implement a javascript file in a wordpress document?

Tags: php, wordpress, head

how can I insert a javascript on one site of my wordpress website? I read, that it could be done with the function `add_action('wp_head', 'function');`
But somehow this doesnt work for me.

Thanks for your help!
phpheini

Answer (score 0):

create a function in your functions.php file (in your theme) and then add. For example,

```
function my_custom_javascript{
print("<script language = 'javascript'>alert('trying my javascript alerts');</script>");
)
add_action('wp_head', 'my_custom_javascript');
```

Comment: Very nice! And how would you do it if you want it to be just in one file?